# D3 mousedown triggers on load

Tags: d3.js

mousedown and mouseup triggering on load and then not again. 
I'm doing something wrong here. 
Any tips appreciated.

-------- mousecrazy.js ----------

```
yesClick = function() {
    alert("always");
}

var svgbox = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 250)
    .on("mousedown", yesClick())
    .on("mouseup", yesClick());
```

-------- mousecrazy.html ----------

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/mousecrazy.js"></script>
    <title>mousecrazy</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .on("mousedown", yesClick()) replace this with .on("mousedown", yesClick)

Not sure in this, but worth a try

Comment: Tried that and nothing happens. That is the alert doesn't fire on load or mousedown.

Comment: You need to add an 'onload' event probably. ( I can't see it anywhere in the provided source code. )

Comment: You need to load the script in the `body` tag and not in the `head`. Otherwise, `body` won't be defined when you run the script and nothing will be appended.

Comment: Script in body tag and placing the function before initializing the svg works. Thanks Lars Kotthoff - had it in body and moved it and ...